# Export SQL Server to Shapefile with OGR, difference between 2014 and 2012

Tags: shapefile, sql-server, ogr

I'm trying to export some data from a SQL Server table to a shapefile.

I have tested this on a 2014 SQL Sever and it works but when I try and run it on a 2012 SQL Server it creates a blank output.

The original that works SQL Server, 2014. Result is as expected with a shapefile created:

`ogr2ogr -overwrite -f "ESRI Shapefile" "C:\temp\sqlexport_Works.shp" "MSSQL:server=[SERVER];database=[DB];trusted_connection=yes;GeometryFormat=native;" -sql "SELECT TOP 1000 [ID] ,GEOMETRY::STGeomFromWKB([geom].STAsBinary(),3857) As [geom] FROM [DB].[dbo].[RoadNetwork] WHERE [geom].STGeometryType() = 'MULTILINESTRING'" -lco "SHPT=ARC" -mapFieldType Binary=String`

The alternative version, that does not work on SQL Server, 2012. Result is an empty shapefile with only a populated dbf file created:

`ogr2ogr -overwrite -f "ESRI Shapefile" "C:\temp\sqlexport_DoesNotWork.shp" "MSSQL:server=[SERVER];database=[DB];trusted_connection=yes;GeometryFormat=native" -sql "SELECT TOP 1000 [ID] ,GEOMETRY::STGeomFromWKB([geom].STAsBinary(),3857) As [geom] FROM [DB].[dbo].[RoadNetwork] WHERE [geom].STGeometryType() = 'MULTILINESTRING'" -lco "SHPT=ARC" -mapFieldType Binary=String`

Can anybody explain how to get this working on SQL Server 2012?

Comment: Compare what you get with ogrinfo command `ogrinfo [your connection and sql] --debug on`.

Comment: Ok thanks for this, there is a difference.  The 2012 server doesn't have a block with the coordinate system information in it. How do I track down if it's a SQL Server issue of OGR install issue?

Comment: Ogrinfo acts here only as a client that makes a SQL query. I am quite sure that there is some difference in databases.